# JVM Tunning of Java Class

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

My java class reads in a 60MB file and produces a `HashMap` of a `HashMap` with over 300 million records.

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Double>> pairWise =
                             new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Double>>();
```

I already tunned the VM argument to be:

```
-Xms512M -Xmx2048M
```

But system still goes for:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.createEntry(HashMap.java:869)
    at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:856)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:484)
    at com.Kaggle.baseline.BaselineNew.createSimMap(BaselineNew.java:70)
    at com.Kaggle.baseline.BaselineNew.<init>(BaselineNew.java:25)
    at com.Kaggle.baseline.BaselineNew.main(BaselineNew.java:315)
```

How big of the heap will it take to run without failing with an OOME?

Comment: Trying to build a 300mio x 300mio similarity matrix is a pretty bad idea, even if you have 2gb of heap.

Comment: Using a simplified test I measure something like 90 bytes for a `Map.Entry<Integer, Double>` so 300 million entries require at least 25GB (probably considerably more than that since you'll also have a bunch of `Map.Entry<Integer, HashMap<...>>` and other things in memory)

Answer (score 5):

**Your dataset is ridiculously large to process it in memory, this is not a final solution, just an optimization.**

You're using boxed primitives, which is a very painful thing to look at.
According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9037808/1768238), a boxed integer can be 20 bytes larger than an unboxed integer. This is not what I call *memory efficient*.

You can optimize this with specialized collections, which don't box the primitive values. One project providing these is [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/). You could use a [`TIntDoubleMap`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/TIntDoubleMap.html) instead of your `HashMap<Integer, Double>` and a [`TIntObjectHashMap`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TIntObjectHashMap.html) instead of your `HashMap<Integer, …>`.

Therefore your type would look like this:

```
TIntObjectHashMap<TIntDoubleHashMap> pairWise =
                         new TIntObjectHashMap<TIntDoubleHashMap>();
```

Now, do the math.

300.000.000 `Double`s, each 24 bytes, use 7.200.000.000 bytes of memory, that is 7.2 GB.
If you store 300.000.000 `double`s, taking 4 bytes each, you only need 1.200.000.000 bytes, which is 1.2 GB.
Congrats, you saved around 83% of the memory you previously used for storing your numbers!

*Note that this calculation is rough, depends on the platform and implementation, and does not account for the memory used for the HashMap/T*Maps*.

Comment: Thx, it seeems a good solution. I downloaded the jar. But it seems cannot imported as other jar libraries? Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your intention, neither do I know what environment you develop in. I assume Eclipse or IntelliJ, and in both of these it should work straightforward. I cannot help you without further information.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I use Eclipse. The jar file of trove-3.0.3-src.jar was imported to the project as usual from build path. When creat a TIntObjectHashMap, there is no package to import...

Comment: Download [this](https://bitbucket.org/robeden/trove/downloads/trove-3.1a1.zip), unzip, `cd` there, call `ant` and the needed files are generated. You can now proceed packing these or copying these.

Comment: Oh, it seems you can also call `ant dist` and copy the resulting `.jar` from `/output/dist/…/trove-…-src.jar`.

Comment: Okay... It seems I need Ant for Mac first. I will try this tonight. Just to make sure that, once I got the files after the ant command, I will do the normal import steps in Eclipse, right?

Comment: I don't use Eclipse, but I think you it should work like that.

Answer (score 3):

Your data set is large enough that holding all of it in memory at one time is not going to happen.

Consider storing the data in a database and loading partial data sets to perform manipulation.

Edit: My assumption was that you were going to do more than one pass on the data.  If all you are doing is loading it and performing one action on each item, then Lex Webb's suggestion (comment below) is a better solution than a database.  If you are performing more than one action per item, then database appears to be a better solution.  The database does not need to be an SQL database, if your data is record oriented a NoSQL database might be a better fit.

Comment: Alternatively just don't read the whole file at once, if possible, read and process the information bit by bit.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong data structures for data of this volume. Java adds significant overhead in memory and time for every object it creates -- and at the 300 million object level you're looking at a lot of overhead. You should consider leaving this data in the file and use random access techniques to address it in place -- [take a look at memory mapped files using nio](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/683614/Things-to-Know-about-Memory-Mapped-File-in-Java).